# Best way to add & store profile photos to Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

I have a screen where the user can add up to 4 photos to his profile one by one. These photos will be stored on Firebase.

The problem is that I do not know how to do simple with Image Picker since there are 4 different containers on the same screen. I'm also trying to find the best way to store these photos.

Here is my current code:

```
func setUserPhoto1 (image : UIImage) {

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://...com")

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)! as NSData

    // set upload path

    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\("userPhoto1")"
    let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return

        }else{

            //store downloadURL

            let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

            //store downloadURL at database

            self.ref.child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["userPhotoUrl1": downloadURL])

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add the next picture (setUserPhoto2) in the same way it is still the first photo that is replaced.

My Database looks like:

```
users
   - uid
      - name
      - photoUrl1
      - photoUrl2
      ...
```

Do you have advice or concrete examples that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you need to store a new image create new unique name for image and store that image name in you database corresponding to your name.

```
let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid).child("\(imageName).jpg")

    if let profileImage = image,let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                return
            }

            if let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

                let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "profileImageUrl\(referenceNumber)": profileImageUrl]
                self.registerUserIntoDatabaseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
            }
        })
    }
```